# Trying to boot Windows 7 from USB with Ubuntu installed

Tags: 16.04, boot, usb, windows-7

Yesterday, I installed Ubuntu, because my Windows 7 crashed and wouldn't boot. I downloaded Windows 7 and burnt it on a usb using multibootusb. So I rebooted my PC, pressed <kbd>F12</kbd> for boot options, selected USB, however, I was met with this screen:

[image: GRUB menu with Ubuntu, advanced options, memory test]

(note that this isn't my picture but one I found online that looked similar)

Every option on the boot menu seems to lead to this screen or just boots Ubuntu. No option leads me to the Windows installer. Any help?

Comment: It looks like you are not really booting from that USB drive. The screen you see is the linux boot loader that is likely the one on your disk.

Comment: Go into BIOS. What device is shown first in your boot order?

Comment: @PaulBenson it says Hard Disk for first, as for 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense at the moment. You pressed F12 and saw an option to boot up a USB device. That is just a subset of the BIOS settings showing all boot menu options. But when you go into full BIOS, you can't see this device in the boot options there?

Comment: @PaulBenson I solved it, I unmounted the USB and reburnt the .iso on the USB and it worked!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out something went wrong with burning the .iso on the USB. I removed the USB and tried burning it again and it worked!